# mv funciona con varios archivos pero solo con uno no

Tags: nodejs

Me pasa que cuando cargo varios archivos lo realiza sin inconvenientes, pero cuando cargo uno solo me devuelve un error de tipo "TypeError: attachment.mv is not a function" comparto el trozo de código

```
                let attachment = req.files.attachments[key];
                var now = Date.now();
                var uniqueFileName = now + '_' + attachment.name;
                //move photo to uploads directory
                attachment.mv(`./attachments/` + uniqueFileName);
```

Comment: ese trozo de codigo no tiene directorio de destino

Comment: el destino es './attachments/'